# Button made of an image - Tkinter

Tags: python, button, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter button that uses an image, and when clicked will execute a function on_button(). My current code is shown below.

```
b = Button(root, image = play, command = on_button)
```

However, this is just an image with a grey button outline around it. I want to be able to just have an image that can be clicked to execute on_button, but can't figure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `relief` option.

```
b = Button(root, image=play, command=on_button, relief=FLAT)
```

**UPDATE**

According to @BryanOakley, on OSX, button with relief=FLAT does not work. Use `Label` widget:

```
lb = Label(root, image=play)
lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: on_button)
lb.pack()
```

Comment: That won't work on OSX, because OSX _really_ wants your buttons to look like buttons. In that case you can use a label, and add your own mouse bindings.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Thank you for advice. I added Label version.